# Как записать структуру данных в файл в бинарном виде?

Tags: c++, binary, fstream

```
    void Huffman::bitYaz(Dugum* alt_dugum)
{
    if(dosyaBit.is_open())
    {
        //dosyaBit.write((char*)&alt_dugum->kod,sizeof alt_dugum->kod);
        //dosyaBit<<alt_dugum->kod;
        //dosyaBit.write((char*)&alt_dugum->kod,sizeof(alt_dugum->kod));
        while (*alt_dugum) dosyaBit.put (*alt_dugum++);
        dosyaBit.close ();
    }
    else
    {
        dosyaBit.open("bit.dat",ios::binary|ios::out);
        bitYaz(alt_dugum);
    }
}
```

Цель:пытаюсь записать в bit.dat файл,структуру данных в бинарном виде,для сжатия файла,не получается.
Использую дерево Хафмана,сначала считывается текст из файла text.txt,затем все добавляется в дерево Хафмана,и каждого символа двоичный код(созданный при помощи Хафмана)записывается в table.txt,после с помощью этого всего записываю в bit.dat в "битовом" формате,но не получается,пишетто все,и правильно как надо,но размер файла больше чем обычный text.txt файл.

Comment: Если Ваша структрура является POD типом, то ее записать можно легко. Если же нет... тогда придется делать ручную сериализацию.

Comment: Не понятно про что вопрос, то ли про "как записать структуру", то ли "почему хафман больше оригинала". Из примера не понятно что такое Dugun и dosyaBit.

Comment: Покажите объявление структуры. Чтоб видеть какие там данные